# compare an image(or a set of images) to video frames and match it using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi3

what i am trying to do:
I need to fix a webcam(video input) over a **credit card swipe machine** and compare the output images in the video frame to a set of sample images captured in the same camera and position over the machine.
  Is template matching the best method to use ?
Is there any other similar alternatives to template matching that i can use it for my specific purpose?
I will be using raspberry pi 3 along with a camera attached to it for capturing the video, and i will be using OpenCV

I have seen another related question but I want to know **If Template matching is the best way to approach my problem ?**

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUo9Y.jpg)

Comment: If it is the same object, but it could be rotated or partially occluded or scaled (zoom in/out effect), then template matching probably will fail, but you can use some of the feature matching algorithms like SURF. If it will stay always in a similar rotation with no scaling then yes, it will work. However raspberry pi processing power may be insufficient for a lot of the computer vision algorithms...

Comment: @api55 yes,   no rotation and scaling just a static setup and the sample image is added to the original question, the image is from a software so it is always the same(no changes or not in motion)

Comment: it should work, but it may give problems if the illumination changes too much :)